# StringIndesOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=2 error in Java

Tags: java, string

This is my code:

```
String bericht = "";

while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        if (cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address")).equals("SAH")) {
            bericht += cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("body"));
            adress = getadress(bericht); //basically cutting a part out
            datum = getdatum(bericht);  //same
            afspraken[x][0] = datum;
            afspraken[x][1] = adress;
            x++;
        }
        cur.moveToNext();
        bericht = "";
    }
```

It works without the `bericht = "";` at the end but I want to reset the string with every loop!

I tried:

```
String bericht;
bericht = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("body"));
```

Error message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(3171): java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=2
```

Comment: Can you also post the code of `getadress()` and `getdatum()`? Where exactly do you get the error? Which line?

Comment: The exception you're posting does not appear in the lines of code you posted above, it appears at some piece of code that tries to access a specific index (maybe a substring()-call or something of that sort) of an empty String.

My guess would be that bericht is empty in some cases so your getadress(...) and getdatum(...) calls would fail to cut something out.

Comment: What line in the code is the StringIndexOutOfBoundsException being thrown on?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you reset the string in every iteration anyway. You can just declare `bericht` inside iteration as you don't need it outside.

```
while (cur.moveToNext()) {
    if (cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address")).equals("SAH")) {
        String bericht = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("body"));
        adress = getadress(bericht); //basically cutting a part out
        datum = getdatum(bericht);  //same
        afspraken[x][0] = datum;
        afspraken[x][1] = adress;
        x++;
    }
    cur.moveToNext();
}
```

Also, it seems that the heart of the problem lies in `getadress(bericht);` or `getdatum(bericht);`. Check how you process your string there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But I get the same error....java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=2

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a guess here since the exception doesn't occur in the code parts posted, but this might help:

```
String bericht = "";

while (cur.moveToNext()) {
    if (cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address")).equals("SAH")) {
        bericht = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("body"));
        if (bericht != null && !bericht.trim().isEmpty()) {
            adress = getadress(bericht); //basically cutting a part out
            datum = getdatum(bericht);  //same
            afspraken[x][0] = datum;
            afspraken[x][1] = adress;
            x++;
        }
    }
    cur.moveToNext();
}
```

What's changed is that we check if the String we put in bericht is something we can reasonably expect to work when calling getadress(...) and getdatum(...) with it. You may want to check even more (minimum length of X for example), but since I can't see what the methods do I can't really tell you what that would be.